# How to store pictures of many users on a webserver?

Tags: php, image, webserver, storage

I need to store number of pictures of many users on the web server (e.g., 5-10 images from 500 - 1000 users, however, over time it can grow more). How can achieve that? I am looking for some design decisions, ideas *from experience*. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest uploading them into a particular folder on the site and renaming then as you upload them to an member ID or some sort of unique identifier.

Comment: How did you do it  finally? And what are your experiences?

Answer (score -1):

Consider using:

- [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) It is widely used & it scales easily
- [Mongodb GridFs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/)

Comment: This is not a design suggestion on how to achieve it technologically.